# Sunspot numbers? forecast? broadcast on CW/HF

Tags: hf, cw

I have vague memories from the early 1990:s of some sort of service that broadcast *something* related to sunspot numbers, in CW, probably shortwave. I think the world "BOULDER" was in there somewhere. Whatever it was, I could hear it in southern Sweden. What was it? Is is still there? On what frequency?

Comment: Do you have [DK0WCY](http://www.dk0wcy.de/schedule_en.html) in mind?

Comment: Well, my memory is so foggy it's hard to say with any certainty, but the callsign feels familiar, and the telegram sample looks familiar, so that's very probably it. Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: That could be WWV. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWV_(radio_station) that is not CW but voice.

Comment: Hello Ture, and welcome to ham.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beacon [DK0WCY](http://www.dk0wcy.de/schedule_en.html) transmits such information on 80 and 30m.