# why does time of day affect propagation when talking to the other side of the earth?

Tags: hf, propagation

i have been told time of day matters for hf propagation. for example, 80m works best at night. but if i qso with someone on the other side of the world, it's daytime. do they just need more power? can i expect to tx better at night and rx better during daytime (or vice versa)?

Comment: The specifics of ionosphere propagation are exactly what makes antipodal DXing ("the other side of the world") on, e.g., 80m difficult, since both your location and your partner's should be located in darkness. Depending on season and location (northern / southern hemisphere), the period of darkness at both ends may be very limited.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to read up on the following articles:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_frequency

With HF ( High Frequency ) the signals are refracted by the "Ionospheric modes (skywave)" back to earth and reflected by the earth itself.

The ionosphere is impacted by the sun spots from the sun.

I've checked this forum and these articles may interest you:

- [Sunspot numbers? forecast? broadcast on CW/HF](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/17574/sunspot-numbers-forecast-broadcast-on-cw-hf)
- [Why do horizontally-polarized RF waves reflect better off ground than vertically-polarized waves?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16859/why-do-horizontally-polarized-rf-waves-reflect-better-off-ground-than-vertically)

Comment: A good example of refraction can be seen by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction